# Java While loop to generate sequence 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working my way through a beginners java book which contains some practice questions to try out. I am currently learning while loops and there is one question that I am stuck on and have been for the last two days.

It is asking me to use a single While loop to print out the first ten numbers in the sequence 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4.

I have worked out the easy bit which is how the sequence goes( add 1, take 2, add 3, take 4, add 5, take 6, add 7 etc.) However I have no idea how to implement this.

```
public class WhileTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First 10 numbers in the sequence 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4, -2 ...");
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 6) {
      int a = 1;
      int num = i;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        num = -i;
      } else {
        num = i;
      }
      a = a + num;
      System.out.print(a+ ", ");
      i++;
```

I know this is no where near close to where I need to get to but I am stuck for ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, how would you do it on paper?  That's a healthy starting point.

Comment: Yes, I was also about to say - use paper & pen to think it through . Once logic is down the coding is trivial. but you know how to code so,,

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, etc?

Comment: Your description starts with 1 and adds 1, thus the series is 1,2... your code starts with 0, does not print out initial value, thus its 1,-1....

Comment: Specify three variables before the loop. One for number of iterations (10), one for the value that will decrement with every second loop, and one that will increment with every second loop. Hope that helps!

Comment: No the sequence is 1,2,0,3,-1,4,-2,5,-3,6. So 1 (+1), 1 (-2), 0 (+3),3(-4), -1(+5), 4(-6),-2(+7),5(-8),-3(+9),6. Thanks for the help guys its helping me understand the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the sequence wrong, look at the numbers:
It starts at 1, then +1, -2 +3 -4 +5 ...

Maybe that helps on your implementation.

Comment: No the sequence is 1,2,0,3,-1,4,-2,5,-3,6. So 1 (+1), 1 (-2), 0 (+3),3(-4), -1(+5), 4(-6),-2(+7),5(-8),-3(+9),6. Thanks for the help guys its helping me understand the problem a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You set a back to 1 inside the loop with each iteration. Shouldn't a be initialized outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that you are a lot closer to a solution than you give yourself credit for.

if you take the `num` and move it outside the loop....

then, you add 1 to `num` each time you loop:

On 'even' loops you add `num`, and on odd loops you subtract `num`. Now, you need to loop 10 times (not until the value is 6.... which is a 'coincidence'....):

Your critical code becomes:

```
int num= 0;
int a = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(a);
    num++;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        a += num;
    } else {
        a -= num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class tester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First 10 numbers in the sequence 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4, -2 ...");
    int num = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int value = 0;
    while (value <= 10) {
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            num = -value;
        } else {
            num = value;
        }
        a = a + num;
        System.out.print(a + ", ");
        value++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. To prevent a *correct* answer from getting downvoted, you need to provide guidance on your decisions. Code blocks should never be a sufficient answer (unless your guidance is commented in the code). Please edit and explain the code. If there is already a working answer, you should explain why your answer is better or an alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

class can't be compiled for the program:-

```
public class WhileTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("First 10 numbers in the sequence 1, 2, 0, 3, -1, 4, -2 ...");
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 6) {
      int a = 1;
      int num = i;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        num = -i;
      } else {
        num = i;
      }
      a = a + num;
      System.out.print(a+ ", ");
      i++;
```

it is a wrong information

Comment: The asker's code clearly isn't intended to be a complete class; he just wrote everything up to here he got stuck. I think he knows that it doesn't compile. And even if he didn't, this is a comment on his question, not an answer to his problem, and copying the whole thing into your answer doesn't add anything.